# Cypher : return collections with unique nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here's a query returning distinct words with their collection of diplomas

```
MATCH (diploma:Diploma)-->(w:Word) 
RETURN DISTINCT w, COLLECT(diploma) as diplomas, COUNT(diploma) as nb_diplomas
ORDER BY nb_diplomas DESC
```

(EDITED : remove OPTIONAL MATCH and use Diploma instead of User in COUNT, remove Resume)

A Diploma can contain several Word and will appear in several collections.
I want this query to return each diploma only once, in the first collection, meaning the collection that contains the most Diploma nodes

Comment: that `OPTIONAL MATCH` is completely separate from the rest of your query. is `result_node` supposed to be something you've already matched?

Comment: result_node is actually diploma ( I've already matched), sorry

Comment: `nb_users` is totally independent from the `Word` here; your query is basically going to return nonsense, because each `:Diploma` applies to the same number of users regardless of the `:Word`. Did you perhaps mean that `(w:Word) <-- (ltr:Resume)` instead?

Comment: OK, I see, I edited the question to simplify the query, removing optional match and using Diploma instead of User in the count

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue; # of resumes is also independent of the word, and is constant for a Diploma.

Comment: I removed the Resume relationship, still no hope ? meaning no way to end up with collections containing unique Word

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126348/discussion-between-armedwing-and-tore-eschliman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you @InverseFalcon for your suggestion, I finally find my way thanks to the UNWIND function

```
MATCH (diploma:Diploma)-->(w:Word) 
WITH DISTINCT w, COLLECT(diploma) AS diplomas 
WITH w, diplomas, LENGTH(diplomas) as nb 
ORDER BY nb DESC 
UNWIND diplomas as diploma 
WITH DISTINCT diploma, HEAD(COLLECT(w)) as w, MAX(nb) as nb
WITH DISTINCT w, COLLECT(diploma) as diplomas 
WITH w, diplomas, LENGTH(diplomas) as nb  
ORDER BY nb DESC 
RETURN w, diplomas, nb
```

Answer (score 0):

So even though a :Diploma is associated with many :Words, you are only interested in the :Word that is most frequently used in the :Diploma, then output rows for each :Word and the related :Diplomas based on that previously filtered frequency?

This may be a good start:

```
MATCH (diploma:Diploma)-->(w:Word) 
WITH diploma, w, COUNT(w) as frequency
WITH diploma, w 
WHERE frequency = MAX(frequency)
RETURN w, COLLECT(diploma) as diplomas, COUNT(diploma) as nb_diplomas
ORDER BY nb_diplomas DESC
```

Keep in mind that if there are multiple words with the same max count in the diploma, that diploma will be associated with both words, and appear in both collections at the end.

To get around that if needed, you'll need to pick the head of a collection of those max words in the middle of the query, something like:

```
MATCH (diploma:Diploma)-->(w:Word) 
WITH diploma, w, COUNT(w) as frequency
WITH diploma, w 
WHERE frequency = MAX(frequency)
WITH diploma, COLLECT(w) as words
WITH diploma, HEAD(words) as w
RETURN w, COLLECT(diploma) as diplomas, COUNT(diploma) as nb_diplomas
ORDER BY nb_diplomas DESC
```

Comment: sounds close. I got an invalid syntax error on `WHERE frequency = MAX(frequency)`, I tried `WITH diploma, w, MAX(frequency) as frequency` It works but doesn't bring the expected results